# Sitecore User Manager error "Invalid 'skip' value in paging input"

Tags: sql-server, sitecore, sitecore7.2

When going page by page, getting error from 20 page onwards (domain is change on after 20th page) in Sitecore user Manager.

[image: User Manager Error]

If any guidelines how to solve this issue it is very usefull.
(using Sitecore 7.2)

Is there any function or method (store procedure or somthing) to get all registered users under each domain from sitecore.?

Comment: Can you please give us more details? What exactly happens on 'domain change'?

Comment: Are you using a Custom Membership provider? Have you implemented the methods supporting paging?

Comment: I need to get all users from API (try both UserManager.GetUsers()  and  Domains.Domain.GetDomain("MyDomain").GetUsers()). 
 it getting same issue.  But in GetDomain("MyDomain").GetUsers() method work only for 'sitecore' domain. I need to get all users from sitecore API.

Comment: @WesleyLomax, Implemented custom membership provider, bt not implemented the methods for supporting paging.